# heredoc's, redirects and file descriptors

Tags: shell, heredoc

I know there are lots of posts in here about heredocs and also redirects and file descriptors, but I can't seem to find anything related to what I want to do.

I want to open a file descriptor to a file and then write a heredoc to that file descriptor.

Here's what I have using bash shell:

```
exec 3>/tmp/testfile.txt
cat <<EOF>>3
write to fd using heredoc
EOF
```

I check my file and its empty. I'm assuming its empty because the reference to my file descriptor in the heredoc goes to the bit bucket. I tried using an ampersand `&` like this `EOF>>&3` but that throws an error in the shell.

How can I get this accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK here's the answer:

```
exec 3>/tmp/testfile.txt
cat <<EOF 1>&3
this is a redirect to fd 3 via a heredoc
EOF
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But you need to explain what you're doing.  Also, please learn to write the code, then indent it by selecting it and using the **`{}`** button above the edit box.  This looks better than using 'inline' code enclosed between back-quotes.  It also allows you to write back-quotes in your shell script, though you shouldn't normally be using those anyway.

Comment: The reason I wanted to use a fd in this instance is to easily allow a function to determine if the fd is created then it's ok to write, else don't attempt. I'm using it with a few other functions to create a dynamic html file using heredoc.

Comment: That looks an awful lot like what I said.  If my answer solved your problem, it's polite to check the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you write:

```
echo something >> 3
```

This will create a *filed* called `3`.  If you want to refer to a file descriptor, you need to use the `&3` syntax.  If you want to append to a file using a file descriptor, you can do this:

```
exec 3>>/tmp/testfile.txt
cat <<EOF >&3
This is a test.
EOF
```

That is, you decide append vs. overwrite when you open the file descriptor with the `exec` statement.  If you did this instead:

```
exec 3>/tmp/testfile.txt
```

That would overwrite the file rather than appending to it.

Comment: I've run into an issue here with the heredoc and redirects. If I open a file descriptor (fd3) to a file how is it that other functions I have that are writing out to STDOUT are getting written to the file descriptor?

Comment: You would need to show us what the rest of your code looks like.  You probably want to open a new question, because comments really aren't suitable for showing code.

Comment: Here's the new question posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944900/stdout-output-getting-written-to-custom-file-descriptor

Answer (score 0):

The Bash manual for [append redirection](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Appending-Redirected-Output) says:

> The general format for appending output is:
>
> ```
> [n]>>word
> ```

You appended to a file `3`.  However, in practice, you don't need the `>>` operator; you need to send the standard output of `cat` to descriptor 3:

```
cat <<EOF 1>&3
write to fd using heredoc
EOF
```

This won't truncate the file, so it achieves 'append' anyway.